# What is the best data structure to store 1 key and 2 values in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I want to store data that looks like this:

```
NAME SURNAME BIRTHDATE
```

e.g.:

```
{{"Anna", "Smith", "16/06/1965"}
{"Bob", "Smith", "26/07/1982"}}
```

I think I can make a struct myself like this:

```
struct PEOPLE {
    string name;
    string surname;
    string birthdate;
};
```

But is there any data structure I can use for this purpose? Like where name is a key and surname and birthdates are values?

Comment: `std::map<std::string, std::pair<std::string, std::string>>`, `std::map<std::string, PEOPLE>`?

Comment: What should your "unique key" be? Approach this like a database problem.

Comment: Also, you ought to read [_"Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names_" by Patrick McKenzie](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [map](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) or [multimap](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/), with `name` as key and a `struct` (with `surname`, `birthdate`, and whatever else you want in it) as value, but note that however you do it, in your application you will probably want the key to be unique for every entry, and `name` will possibly not be.

Answer (score 2):

You can always have something like:

```cpp
using Key   = std::string;
using Value = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;
```

and use it like:

```cpp
using HumanBeing = std::pair<Key, Value>;
```

or:

```cpp
std::map<Key, Value>
```

Of course, aliases are not that necessary :)